# setup time optimization using statistics

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

together

I work at a manufacturer with numerous products. The diversity if variants is very high. For almost every product the machines have to be converted. There are essentially 3 characteristics, which determine the time for the conversion. That's the kind, the diameter, and another practical criterion.
The aim is to determine the order in which the products must be processed so that the set-up time is as minimal as possible.
The set-up time is different here.
That is, the setup time of product A on product B is 1 hour.
However, the setup time from Product C to Product B is only 30 minutes.

I now have the following database:
Setup time - product before
60 min - product A
45 min - product C
20min - Product A1
40min - Product A

These data refer to the last 2 years.
What kind of analysis, approach would you recommend to determine correlations not specific to the specific product characteristics? Should the data be further broken down before?
Maybe in:

Setup Time - Product - Product Type - Product Diameter - Criterion C?

I'm happy about any hint.
Maybe someone might even have literature that has followed the same approach.

With best regards

Comment: Welcome to MSW. Perhaps that it would be more appropriate to post that question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Lets try, thanks for that!